# Calculating $e^{j2\pi t}$ in two ways gives different results: $\cos(2\pi t)+j \sin(2\pi t)$ vs $1^t$

Tags: trigonometry, exponentiation

I've encountered the following equations while studying complex exponentials:
$$\begin{align}
e^{j2\pi t} &= \cos(2\pi t) + j \sin(2\pi t) \tag1\\[4pt]
e^{j2\pi t} &= (e^{j2\pi})^t = (\cos(2\pi) + j\sin(2\pi))^t = (1+0)^t = 1^t \tag2
\end{align}$$
Upon comparing (1) and (2), it's evident that they represent different expressions. However, theoretically, these equations should yield the same result.

Could someone help clarify this result?

Comment: Why do you think that $e^{j2\pi t}=\left(e^{2j\pi}\right)^t$? Actually, what does $\left(e^{2j\pi}\right)^t$ even mean?

Comment: This just shows that complex numbers don't behave like real numbers. You cannot apply the rules you learnt for real numbers to the case of complex numbers.

Comment: Hope this solves your problem.
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/912686/1277478

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of (many) existing questions here?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4488445/how-are-powers-of-complex-numbers-defined/

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136570/determination-of-complex-logarithm